# How to invert the result of the buildin IsEmpty function?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to implement a sort of "`IsNotEmpty`" function.

I tried this way, but I faild:

```
left_var = foreach right_var generate (IsEmpty(myBag) == 'true'?'false':'true'));
```

But I'm getting some syntax error,becouse the Pig compiler recognizes the left side of the if statement as a `boolean` and the right one as a `chararray`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try either

```
left_var = foreach right_var generate (IsEmpty(myBag) ? false : true));
```

or (better)

```
left_var = foreach right_var generate (NOT(IsEmpty(myBag)));
```